Can not Call recv_internal "op:transfer" of jetton wallet contract from another contract
I want to create a smartcontract for deposit jetton token, withdraw jetton token, simply the user calls deposit, will transfer jetton from jetton wallet to contract, and withdraw will transfer jetton from contract to user wallet,
Buy send_jetton doesn't work because err 73:"not owner", is there any way or function to use?
Thank you very much,
My code on contract A call to contract jetton B, but exits code: 73, not owner
Can it be called like my code, and if not, is there a way to create this contract?
() deposit_usdt_jetton(
    slice _sender_address,
    int _ton_amount,
    int _foward_ton_amount,
    int _jetton_amount
) impure inline {
    cell master_msg = begin_cell()
        .store_uint(op::transfer, 32)  
        .store_coins(_jetton_amount)  
        .store_slice(my_address()) 
        .store_slice(my_address())  
        .store_coins(_foward_ton_amount)  
        .store_maybe_ref(null())  
        .end_cell();
    send_to_usdt_jetton_wallet(_sender_address, _ton_amount, master_msg, TRUE);
}

() send_to_usdt_jetton_wallet(slice to_address, int ton_amount, cell master_msg, int need_state_init) impure inline {
    raw_reserve(ONE_TON, RESERVE_REGULAR);
    (int total_supply, slice admin_address, slice next_admin_address, cell jetton_wallet_code, cell metadata_uri, cell config_data, cell management) = load_data();
    (cell moderator, cell verified_user, cell usdt_jetton_wallet_code, slice usdt_address) = load_management(management);
    cell state_init = calculate_jetton_wallet_state_init(to_address, usdt_address, usdt_jetton_wallet_code);
    slice to_wallet_address = calculate_jetton_wallet_address(state_init);

    cell msg = begin_cell()
        .store_uint(0x10, 6) 
        .store_slice(to_wallet_address)
        .store_coins(ton_amount)  
        .store_uint(1, 1 + 4 + 4 + 64 + 32 + 1 + 1)
        .store_ref(master_msg)
        .end_cell();

    send_raw_message(msg, SEND_MODE_PAY_FEES_SEPARATELY | SEND_MODE_BOUNCE_ON_ACTION_FAIL);
}

